# How to print all keys from an object each on a separate line

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I can not figure out how to print each key on a separated line.

The function prints each key of the input on a separate line. That is, it prints all keys of the key-value store separated by new line characters.

I'm able to print all the keys, just not on separate lines like it asks.

```
function print_keys(x){
console.log(Object.keys(x));
}
```

Expected 
"stand
rip
rating
pollution
fixed
"
But got "stand,rip,rating,pollution,fixed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array, so you should iterate on it. Like this:

```
function print_keys(x){
    var keys = Object.keys(x);
    for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
       console.log(keys[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `forEach`:

```js
var obj = {
  name: "Jack",
  age: 300,
  leet: true
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => console.log(key));
```

Alternatively, you could print them all in the one `console.log` statement using `join` with a newline `\n`:

```js
var obj = {
  name: "Jack",
  age: 300,
  leet: true
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj).join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys(x) will return you an array and print the array through console.log. An array can be iterated through, and each individual item examined for printing. That's likely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys returns an array, simply turn the ruslt into string like this;

`console.log(Object.keys(x).toString());`